# .Net: Is this a clumsy or a clever way of managing application states? (Stopped|Running|Paused|StopPending|StartPending|PausePending|ContinuePending)

Tags: .net, windows-services, state

I am developing a Windows Service application of some complexity, and need to have a way of gracefully transitioning between states. Since each state might need initialization / cleaning up, there must be a mechanism that coordinates the transitions between them and makes sure only valid states can be reached from any given state. The states in question are the familiar states of a Windows Service:

`Stopped|Running|Paused|StopPending|StartPending|PausePending|ContinuePending`

I have developed a system that *seems* to do this properly, but I am curious whether it has flaws that I just haven't stumbled over yet and/or if there are more tried-and-tested patterns / best practices that I could or should use instead.

This is implemented in a Bootstrapper class that exposes methods corresponding to the commands I should expect from a Windows Service: Start, Stop, Pause, Continue (so that the Service's OnStart command will simply call the class' Start method, OnStop will call Stop etc):

In the Service code (this is VB.Net, but I had to use // for comments here, since ' seemed to mess things up in the code listing):

```
Sub OnStart()
    Bootstrapper.Start()
End Sub
```

In the `Start()` method of my class (I bypass threading and exception handling and other logic for simplicity here):

```
Public Sub Start()
    If RequestState(State.Running) = True Then
        // Log success
    Else
        // Log failure
    End If
End Sub
```

Then, inside my class, there is a similar set of private `OnStart()`, `OnStop()`, `OnPause()` and `OnContinue()` methods that perform the actual initialization / cleanup for each state:

```
Private Function OnStart() As Boolean
    SetState(State.StartPending)
        // Do something
    Return SetState(State.Running)
End Function
```

As you can see above, there are calls being made to two other methods - `RequestState()` and `SetState()`. That's where the logic actually takes place, and it works as follows:

A command is being sent to the application (Start, Stop, Pause or Continue). The receiving method calls `RequestState()` with the desired end state passed as a parameter. If that state was reachable it returns `True`, otherwise `False`.

`RequestState()` will use `Select` constructs to determine the right action, based on the current state and the requested state.

`SetState()` actually sets the state of the application, and after doing so, checks whether there is some 'next' state 'queued up' (this is so that a StartPending process will be able to finish and end up in a Running state, before a Pause command is issued).

Forgive me if I introduce these methods in a jumbled order, but from where I sit, it seemed like the right way to introduce the functionality. Here are the `RequestState()` and `SetState()` methods (sorry for the sheer length, but I felt it was needed for completeness):

```
Private _currentState As State
Private _nextState As State

Private Function RequestState(ByVal requestedState As State) As Boolean
    Select Case requestedState
        Case State.StartPending, State.StopPending, State.PausePending, State.ContinuePending, State.Exception, State.None
            Throw New ArgumentException(requestedState.ToString & " cannot be requested directly.")
        Case Else

            _nextState = requestedState

            Select Case _currentState
                Case State.Exception
                    Return False

                Case State.Stopped
                    Select Case requestedState
                        Case State.Stopped
                            Return True
                        Case State.Running
                            Return OnStart()
                        Case Else
                            Return False
                    End Select

                Case State.Running
                    Select Case requestedState
                        Case State.Stopped
                            Return OnStop()
                        Case State.Running
                            Return True
                        Case State.Paused
                            Return OnPause()
                        Case Else
                            Return False
                    End Select

                Case State.Paused
                    Select Case requestedState
                        Case State.Stopped
                            Return OnStop()
                        Case State.Running
                            Return OnContinue()
                        Case State.Paused
                            Return True
                        Case Else
                            Return False
                    End Select

                Case State.StartPending
                    Select Case requestedState
                        Case State.Stopped
                            _nextState = State.Stopped
                            Return True
                        Case State.Running
                            Return True
                        Case State.Paused
                            _nextState = State.Paused
                            Return True
                        Case Else
                            Return False
                    End Select

                Case State.StopPending
                    Select Case requestedState
                        Case State.Stopped
                            Return True
                        Case State.Running
                            _nextState = State.Running
                            Return True
                        Case Else
                            Return False
                    End Select

                Case State.ContinuePending
                    Select Case requestedState
                        Case State.Stopped
                            _nextState = State.Stopped
                            Return True
                        Case State.Running
                            Return True
                        Case State.Paused
                            _nextState = State.Paused
                            Return True
                        Case Else
                            Return False
                End Select

                Case State.PausePending
                    Select Case requestedState
                        Case State.Stopped
                            _nextState = State.Stopped
                            Return True
                        Case State.Running
                            _nextState = State.Running
                            Return True
                        Case State.Paused
                            Return True
                        Case Else
                            Return False
                    End Select

                Case Else
                    Return False

            End Select
    End Select
End Function

Private Function SetState(ByVal newState As State) As Boolean
    _currentState = newState
    If newState = State.Running OrElse newState = State.Stopped OrElse newState = State.Paused Then
        If _currentState = _nextState Then
            Return True
        End If
        Return RequestState(_nextState)
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say its ok as-is. There aren't many states and its reasonably easy to follow. I'd say there are some places where you can make the code a bit shorter, but otherwise its not too bad.

However, it *might* be easier creating a real state table. Start by mapping your state table out in a grid like this:

```
Start State        Requested State      State Changed?
-----------        ---------------      --------------
Exception          { any }              False
Stopped            Running              OnStart()
Paused             Stopped              OnStop()
Paused             Running              OnPause()
StartPending       Running              True
StartPending       Paused               True
etc
```

Now to convert this into code, consider that this is basically a `Dictionary<State, Dictionary<State, Func<bool>>>`, where the outer key is your StartState, outer Value is your transition table.

This code is *not tested*, but should give you a general idea of where to start (using C# since my VB-fu is rusty):

```
public bool RequestState(State requestedState)
{
    _nextState = requestedState;
    if (requestedState == currentState)
        return true;

    var stateTransitions = new Dictionary<State, Dictionary<State, Func<bool>>>
    {
        { State.Exception, new Dictionary<State, Func<bool>(),
        { State.Stopped, new Dictionary<State, Func<bool>>
            {
                { State.Running, () => OnStart() }
            }
        },
        { State.Paused, new Dictionary<State, Func<bool>>
            {
                { State.Stopped, () => OnStop() },
                { State.Running, () => OnPause() },
            }
        },
        { State.StartPending, new Dictionary<State, Func<bool>>
            {
                { State.Running, () => true },
                { State.Paused, () => true },
            }
        },
        // remaining states
    };

    var transition = stateTransitions[currentState];
    Func<bool> transitionAction;
    if (transition.TryGetValue(requestedState, out transitionAction))
        return transitionAction();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In addition to this answer, since you have some VB case statements, I personally find the code is a lot more compact by using a colon to put more than one VB statement on the same line  (i.e. `Case State.Whatever: Return True`). Its the same code, just takes up half the space.

Comment: Oh, and you can also rewrite `{ State.Whatever, () => OnStop() }` as `{ State.Whatever, OnStop }`. Either works just fine, using one or the other is a style choice.

Comment: Thanks, Your Awesomeness. I was thinking about using some logic matrix for it, but left it out for reasons of fiddliness at the moment. However, if you notice in my code, there's also the occasional case (with the Pending states), where _nextState needs to be set in the Case statement along with returning the bool. It was the _nextState feature and how the RequestState ties in with SetState that I thought was potentially clever..

Comment: The reason I went with plain Select statements initially (and perhaps finally) was because I was working through my own logic at the same time I was coding, and needed to keep it simple to not confuse myself until the basic principle was nailed down :)